# Getting proper resolution with Windows 7 and older monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I'm trying to connect an older monitor (Starlogic M17ANA) to a newer system with Windows 7, but the only resolutions shown are 1024x768 and 800x600. I know the monitor is capable of 1280x1024, and was running this resolution on an older Windows XP system just fine. The 1024x768 setting has some timing problems and is nearly unusable, while the 800x600 setting is far too small to be useful. I really need to get this setup to the proper resolution.

I tried changing the monitor driver from "Generic PnP Monitor" to "Digital Flat Panel (1280x1024)" but it does not change the settings available. Even the "List All Modes" button doesn't show anything larger than "1024 by 768".

The video driver listed is "Intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset" if that makes a difference. I had the PC connected to a different monitor earlier, and I'm quite sure it was running a higher resolution just fine.

---

**Argh!** For one glorious moment tonight I was able to get the resolution properly configured by selecting the "Generic Non-PnP Monitor" driver and choosing the proper resolution. When the system went into low-power mode after a period of inactivity it switched back to the lower resolution. Now it seems no matter which monitor I select I still only get the two choices - 800x600 and 1024x768. I've rebooted a dozen times and nothing changes. I've loaded all the latest Windows updates, including the driver for the Q45/Q43 chipset and still nothing changes. Why is Windows locking me out of choices that the hardware and drivers are perfectly capable of handling?

---

**Conclusion:** I should have pointed out that this was an LCD monitor, I think some people assumed when I said "older" that it was a CRT. I now believe that the problem is specific to this model; it appears to deliver the wrong [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) information to the driver, and Windows 7 treats it as gospel. Downloading the latest driver from Intel rather than Microsoft included an extra utility that was able to extend the profile with a custom setting, which works perfectly.

Comment: it sounds some like your limited to "compatability mode" video resolutions, as if the driver for the GPU item is not installed or working properly yet.  (check your video drivers in the device manager).  . Do you have this same problem with any other monitor hooked up exactally the same way to the exact same port?

Comment: What's the graphic card hardware ID? Which driver version are you currently using? Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @and31415 the adapter is built into the motherboard. There are 4 hardware IDs listed in device manager: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&SUBSYS_3036103C&REV_03 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&SUBSYS_3036103C PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&CC_030000 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&CC_0300. The driver version is 8.15.10.1749 and it's Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

Comment: The current driver is quite old (2009), and probably is the one bundled with Windows 7. Latest available version is 15.17.19.2869 (8.15.10.2869), which you can get from the [official Intel support page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=Intel+Q43+Express+Chipset). Restart Windows after updating the driver, and see whether you can choose a 1280x1024 resolution.

Comment: @and31415 I got the latest from the Intel site, no help.

Comment: The driver version was updated successfully, right? Start `regedit.exe`, and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000`. Check if there's any value called either `DTD_1` or `TotalDTDCount`. Download and run [Monitor Asset Manager](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm). Select the "Real-item" item from the display IDs list and copy the asset information, then upload the text to http://pastebin.com/. Repeat the same steps for the "Registry" and "Registry-Active" items.

Comment: @and31415 the driver version reported in driver properties is 8.15.10.2869. Regedit shows 5 DTD entries but TotalDTDCount is 0. Results from Monitor Asset Manager are at http://pastebin.com/XZMtc7ti http://pastebin.com/ih89yB4V and http://pastebin.com/qEatJDNZ.

Comment: @and31415 I tried the Intel utility that was installed with the driver and it let me create a 1280x1024 profile. Once I unchecked the "Hide modes" checkbox I was allowed to choose it, and it's working! Let's see if it will hold this time.

Comment: @MarkRansom Since you have an older monitor, there should be a sticker on the back that tells you the supported refresh rates of the monitor. Depending on the manufacturer, it might list the low and highest refresh rate supported by resolution. Windows "hides" some of these refresh rates, as damage may occur if you use too high of a refresh rate on a monitor that doesn't support it. Your settings should hold now.

Comment: @MarkRansom The problem is the system thinks you have a 15.2" monitor with a max supported resolution of 1024x768 pixels and 68 Hz refresh rate. That needs to be fixed, otherwise the resolution is likely to be reset again sometime in the future (e.g. after stand-by/suspend).

Comment: @and31415 you've actually solved my problem. Please leave an answer so I don't have to waste the bonus.

Comment: @and31415: Please include in your answer the tools used, like Monitor Asset Manager. I find it interesting how you have arrived at your conclusions.

Comment: @MarkRansom You mean the default Intel configuration program? What's the utility name? Can you confirm that the screen resolution remains unchanged even when the monitor switches back from the low-power mode? Has the `TotalDTDCount` value changed? Could you repeat the steps I described earlier using the Monitor Asset Manager tool?

Comment: @and31415 I'm asked to approve about 4 different apps when I log in. The utility I spoke of is called GfxUI.exe and it's located in Windows\System32. The resolution seems to be holding. `TotalDTDCount` is still 0. Monitor Asset Manager is now erroring out when I start it so I'm unable to rerun those tests.

Comment: @MarkRansom You mean approve as in requiring admin rights? Out of curiosity, what's the error returned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Analysis

After doing a quick search, there are some other people with the same issue, most of which didn't solve it. I also found a [blog post](http://basictech.wordpress.com/tag/starlogic/) explaining how to solve the problem in Windows 2000, which basically involved doing the steps you probably did back when using Windows XP, albeit without success in Windows 7.

### Monitor

I couldn't find much information at all. This is what I collected from an old [DriverGuide thread](http://forums.driverguide.com/showthread.php?t=12261):

> #### 17" StarLogic LCD Monitor (11004988)
>
> **Model** M17ANA
> **Resolution** 1280 x 1024
> **Display colors** 16.7 million colors
> **Pixel Pitch** 0.264 mm
> **Brightness** 260 cd/m<sup>2</sup>
> **Contrast ratio** 400:1
> **Viewing angle** 140 x 125 degree
> **Response time** 12 ms
> **Sync. frequency** Horizontal 31.5kHz - 79.9kHz, Vertical 70Hz - 75Hz
> **Input Connector** RGB
> **Weight** 8.14 lbs.

This at least confirms the monitor is actually capable of displaying a 1280x1024 resolution. Still, the proper resolution isn't applied, and isn't even listed in the available modes.

### Graphic card

In this case the graphic card model is an **Intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset**, which is integrated in the motherboard. According to the [technical product specifications](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/16959/eng/DQ45EK_TechProdSpec.pdf):

> Supports digital and analog displays up to 2048 x 1536 at 75 Hz refresh
> (QXGA); also supports 1920 x 1080 resolution for full High Definition video
> playback quality.
>
> The video modes supported by this board are based on the Extended Display
> Identification Data (EDID) modes of the monitor to which the system is connected.
> Standard monitors are assumed.

The graphic card doesn't seem a limiting factor. These are the specific hardware IDs:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&SUBSYS_3036103C&REV_03
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&SUBSYS_3036103C
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&CC_030000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&CC_0300
```

The generic hardware IDs actually is `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12`. In fact, apparently there are only generic drivers available for such cards. The installed driver version was **8.15.10.1749**, which dates back to 2009, and probably was the one bundled with Windows 7. The latest version available from [Intel official support page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=Intel+Q43+Express+Chipset) is **8.15.10.2869**, released about three years later.

On a side note, looking for an updated version through Windows Update can be misleading: the system will happily assume the driver is "up to date" even when no entry was found in Microsoft database.

### Extended Display Identification Data

> All monitors, analog or digital, must support EDID, which contains info such as the monitor identifier, manufacturer data, hardware identifier, timing info, and so on. This data is stored in the monitor’s EEPROM in a format that is specified by the Video Electronics Standards Association (VESA).
>
> <sub>Source: [Overriding Monitor EDIDs with an INF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

While the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) data structure is not exactly human-friendly, we can use [Monitor Asset Manager](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm) to examine it:

```
Monitor
  Manufacturer............. NUL
  Plug and Play ID......... NUL0001
  Serial number............ 1
  Manufacture date......... 2001, ISO week 1
  Filter driver............ None
  -------------------------
  EDID revision............ 1.3
  Input signal type........ Analog 0.700,0.300 (1.0V p-p)
  Sync input support....... Separate
  Display type............. RGB color
  Screen size.............. 310 x 230 mm (15.2 in)
  Power management......... Standby, Suspend
  Extension blocs.......... None
  -------------------------
  DDC/CI................... Not supported
 
Color characteristics
  Default color space...... Non-sRGB
  Display gamma............ 1.00
  Red chromaticity......... Rx 0.597 - Ry 0.343
  Green chromaticity....... Gx 0.316 - Gy 0.566
  Blue chromaticity........ Bx 0.153 - By 0.131
  White point (default).... Wx 0.310 - Wy 0.328
  Additional descriptors... None
 
Timing characteristics
  Range limits............. Not available
  GTF standard............. Not supported
  Additional descriptors... None
  Preferred timing......... Yes
  Native/preferred timing.. 1024x768p at 68Hz (4:3)
    Modeline............... "1024x768" 65.000 1024 1048 1184 1184 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
 
Standard timings supported
     720 x  400p at  70Hz - IBM VGA
     640 x  480p at  60Hz - IBM VGA
     800 x  600p at  60Hz - VESA
    1024 x  768p at  60Hz - VESA
 
Report information
  Date generated........... 2/12/2014
  Software revision........ 2.70.0.989
  Data source.............. Real-time 0x0011
  Operating system......... 6.1.7601.2.Service Pack 1
 
Raw data
  00,FF,FF,FF,FF,FF,FF,00,3A,AC,01,00,01,00,00,00,01,0B,01,03,08,1F,17,00,CA,F0,64,98,57,51,91,27,
  21,4F,54,A1,08,00,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,64,19,00,A0,40,00,26,30,18,88,
  36,00,30,E4,10,00,00,18,00,00,00,FE,00,0A,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,FE,00,0A,
  20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,FC,00,0A,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,00,E
```

Windows stores the EDID in the registry after querying the monitor. The problem is the system thinks you have a 15.2" monitor with a maximum supported resolution of 1024x768 pixels and 68 Hz refresh rate. This is just plain wrong, and the monitor is to blame here.

## Conclusion

The monitor won't report the correct information, so we have to manually fix that. There are a few ways to do it, and I'll briefly describe them referring you to the links below for additional information. It's better to have more options just in case something doesn't work properly or isn't applicable.

### Intel Graphics Control Panel

While updating the old, bare-bone graphic driver which comes with Windows you'll also get the [Intel Graphics Control Panel](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-022130.htm) (`GfxUI.exe`). Among other things, it can be used to change the screen resolution.

### Custom resolution

Some (but not all) Intel graphic cards can support up to five extra Detailed Timing Descriptors (DTDs) through custom registry entries named `DTD_x` which can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-‌​08002BE10318}\0000`. Each DTD value includes information such as screen resolution, refresh rates, and so on. The `TotalDTDCount` value controls the amount of DTD supported. When it's set to `0`, the feature is disabled.

The DTD is actually a section of the full EDID, and it's just as cryptic. In order to easily change the data you can use [DTDCalculator](http://www.clevertec.co.uk/productsfree.htm).

### Correcting the EDID

> There are two approaches to correcting EDIDs:
>
> - The standard solution is to have the customer send the monitor back to the manufacturer, who reflashes the EEPROM with the correct EDID and returns the monitor to the customer.
> - A better solution, described here, is for the manufacturer to implement an INF file that contains the correct EDID info, and have the customer download it to the computer that's connected to the monitor. Windows extracts the updated EDID info from the INF and provides it to components instead of the info from the EEPROM EDID, effectively overriding the EEPROM EDID.
>
> <sub>Source: [Overriding Monitor EDIDs with an INF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

Using [Phoenix EDID designer](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/9016d1240813004-force-dvi-hdmi-resolutions-refresh-rates-phoenix.zip) you can extract the EDID stored in the registry, and change the settings to reflect the monitor true capabilities. When done you save the modified EDID data, and open it using Monitor Asset Manager to validate it. Then you create an INF file, and update the monitor driver in the Device Manager using the file you just created. A restart is required to apply the changes.

## Further reading

- [Intel Desktop Board DQ45EK Technical Product Specification](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/16959/eng/DQ45EK_TechProdSpec.pdf)
- [Discovering Hardware IDs and Device Setup Classes for your Devices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733122%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Understanding The Intel Graphics Driver Version Number](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-020667.htm)
- [Extended display identification data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data)
- [Custom Resolutions on Intel Graphics](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/custom-resolutions-on-intel-graphics)
- [A list of Common Video Mode-Lines](http://linuxhelp.150m.com/resources/modelines.htm)
- [Modeline Database](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database)
- [Overriding Monitor EDIDs with an INF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to Force DVI or HDMI Resolutions and Refresh Rates in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7947-force-dvi-hdmi-resolutions-refresh-rates.html)

Comment: I agree, nice comprehensive answer - this is totally worth the +50 you're getting. And for the record, the driver I had was not the one originally bundled with Windows 7 but one that I received through Windows Update.

Comment: @MarkRansom I beg to differ: the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Rss.aspx?q=Windows+7+VEN_8086%26DEV_2E12) provides different driver versions ranging from build **1808** to **2302**, but not anything older. In fact, the Intel driver is located in the `Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh.inf_x86_neutral_2d255f193700d214` folder in Windows 7 x86 (32-bit). The version reported in the `igdlh.inf` installation file is 8.15.10. **1749**.

Comment: All I know is that Windows Update offered me an optional update that said it was specifically for that driver. Unfortunately I don't know what the version was before the update, nor did I check to see if the update installed successfully.

Comment: @MarkRansom Odd. Windows keeps every driver you install unless you explicitly remove them for good; this way you can easily roll back to a previous version if necessary. Searching `igdlh.inf` inside the `DriverStore` directory should bring up all versions available.

Answer (score 2):

As 1280x1024 is not the same x-y ratio as 1280x1024 and 800x600, how are you displaying them all on the same monitor? Do you have black bands while doing that?

If you wish to play with [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) profiles, you could use
[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm), a shareware utility that can create new custom resolutions for your monitor.
You could also use it to investigate the existing EDID information.

See for example :

[Custom display modes (Windows) - Powerstrip](http://wiki.arcadecontrols.com/wiki/Custom_display_modes_%28Windows%29_-_Powerstrip)
[Customize monitor resolution settings with PowerStrip](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-monitor-resolution-settings-with-powerstrip/).

Another possibility is to use regedit and position to this key :
`HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{video-card}\0000`
and change the following keys :
`DefautlSettings.XResolution`, `DefautlSettings.YResolution`,
then reboot.

Comment: Powerstrip isn't free, it's $30 shareware. But it did point out to me the way to get 1024x768 working, by setting the refresh rate to 60hz, so it was helpful for that. Still couldn't get me to 1280x1024 so I uninstalled it. As for the aspect ratio difference I suspect that the resizing logic in the monitor simply makes the pixels non-square at the lower resolutions since it has to rescale them anyway. The difference isn't enough to be noticeable.

Comment: Pixels are never square and cannot be reshaped, which is why our monitors have their ratio. Probably the display driver interpolates the image to display, and does it well. If you have found a method that is not mentioned in my answer, better post your own.