# Monitors not turning on with computer

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport

I have 3 monitors connected through displayport cords and they do not turn on when my PC powers up and only turn on after I hit the PC's reset button.

Here are some details:

Graphics card has 3 displayport ports, 1 HDMI port, and 1 DVI port.

When I first got the PC I was only able to connect one monitor through a DVI cord, no problems. While searching for DP cords so that I could use all 3 monitors at 144Hz I came across 2 HDMI to DP cords so I ran all 3 monitors with them and had no problems (1 DVI and 2 DP to HDMI cords).

When I finally got my hands on 3 DP cords I started having this issue where my monitors wouldn't turn on with my PC and only turned on when I reset my PC. So daily I turn on my PC, wait 20 seconds with blank monitors (they say they are not connected) and then reset it.

This is where it gets weird. I tried 1 DIV cord and 2 DP cords, problem still happened. Then I tried to go back to the 1 DVI and 2 HDMI to DP cords and it works fine. I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm at a loss for a solution. Happened in Windows 8.1 and the problem still happens in Windows 10.

```
StarTech.com DISPLPORT6L DisplayPort Cable with Latches, M/M, 6-Feet

Insignia 1.8 m (6 ft.) DisplayPort/HDMI Cable

Intel Core i7 4790K Unlocked Quad Core HT 4GHZ/4.4GHZ Processor LGA1150 Haswell 8MB Cache

Corsair Cooling Hydro Series H60 CPU Cooler System LGA1150 1155 1366 1156 2011 AM2 AM3 FM1 & FM2

ASUS Maximus VII Ranger ATX LGA1150 Z97 3PCI-E16 3PCI-E1 SATA3 USB3.0 CROSSFIRE/SLI HDMI Motherboard

ASUS GeForce GTX 980 Strix 1279MHZ 4GB 7.0GHZ GDDR5 DVI HDMI 3x DisplayPort PCI-E Video Card

Corsair CS650M CS Modular 80 Plus GOLD-RATE 650W 12V Power Supply

3x ASUS VG248QE 24IN Widescreen 1920x1080 144HZ 1ms HDMI DisplayPort DVI-D 3D Vision LED LCD Monitor

Corsair Force LX 128GB 2.5in Solid State Drive SATA2 SATA3 MLC 7MM 560MB READ/150MB Write SSD

Western Digital WD1003FZEX Black 1TB SATA3 6GB/S 7200RPM 64MB Cache 3.5in Hard Drive OEM
```

Comment: usually If it is only a monitor issues and kicking it in and out of standby , turning off the monitor or putting the cable in and out would trigger the monitor to test if there is a signal or not and start working. I wonder if you have tired that, something you have to do without a view? Otherwise the problem is likely to have something to do with the video card initing at post.  Can you confirm things like the OS starting up anyway, via hard disk activity HD lights, and sounds (like startup sounds) ?    Are you resetting because the computer did not post , or slamming it with the os there?

Comment: I've tried turning the monitors on and off, pulling out and putting in cables, and switching cable ports.


From what I can tell the computer starts up normally and the monitors just aren't working. The fans start, the lights turn on, etc.

Comment: Ok so now you covered the monitor communication stuff from the video card, it is likely to not be that. from what your saying.  If the OS runs or not, is completly different again,. the lights and fans inconsequetial to determining if the video card initied or you got post.  Knowing that the os runs and startup sounds and all (even if it has little value to an actual solution) is night and day difference.  If the video card instead did not init and stops posting from even occuring. Or if the video card inited but fails to display, while the rest of the computer continues on without a view.

Comment: I'll have to research how to test those 2 possibilities when I get home later today.

I tried 1 DVI and 2 DP to HDMI cords again and it fixed the problem. I'm ordering 3 new DP cords and praying it will be as easy as that but have I doubts.

Comment: I can give you an idea: I have similar problem, when attaching HDMI cable to the laptop, every time I'll bring it at the workplace. At my case I found the workaround on the monitor side: monitor menu contains a "sleep mode" which goes to sleep mode regardless of the signal received from the PC. If I enter the sleep mode and leave it, the problem fixes itself. Not the best, but sharing another idea of the workaround. I did not find the cause yet.

Comment: (1) If the graphics card has an Energy Saving mode, switch it to High Performance. (2) Switch Windows to a High performance Power plan. (3) Check for new firmware for the monitors and for the BIOS. (4) Force the EDID information of the monitors as [described here](https://sites.google.com/site/ebobster/stuff/displayportblanking) for Nvidia or (5) see my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/714320/8672).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these :

1. If the graphics card has an Energy Saving mode, switch it to High Performance.
2. Switch Windows to a High performance Power plan.
3. Check for new firmware for the monitors and for the BIOS.
4. For Nvidia only, force the EDID information of the monitors as described
   in the article
   [DisplayPort Blanking / Screen Autodetect Problems](https://sites.google.com/site/ebobster/stuff/displayportblanking).
5. Use the [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) shareware utility to force the EDID information (more info [here](http://wiki.arcadecontrols.com/wiki/Custom_display_modes_%28Windows%29_-_Powerstrip)).
6. Use Displayport cables of better quality.

Comment: I tried these things however in the end when I received my new displayport cables they worked from the start.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've ever decided to post a piece of advice to any website/message board because I think it would really help a lot of people. I had the exactly same problem after installing a new motherboard. I tried everything I could think of and all the tips I found online; to list just a few: updating my BIOS, reinstalling Windows 10, changing from DP cable to HDMI, reinstalling all my drivers, reinstalling just graphics drivers, plugging and unplugging my Nvidia graphics card several times, cleaning/vacuuming every single component (my comp is as clean as a whistle - looks brand new, trying all kinds of combinations in BIOS settings, etc - nothing worked.

And here is how I SOLVED IT! After reading some unrelated advice about the "turn on fast start-up" function in Windows 10 and reading about how it can cause certain booting problems, I thought I might as well give it a try, nothing left to lose. So, I went to Control Panel/Power Options and under "change setting that are currently unavailable" turned off the fast start-up. Voila, problem solved! I'm guessing there is was kind of incompatibility between my motherboard (Intel Desktop Board DQ77MK) and this particular Windows setting. After spending a week dealing with this issue and going out of my ever-loving mind, you can imagine my relief. I'll make sure to post this advice on as many message boards I can to help other miserable souls like myself.